# How to compare string_view using if-constexpt in a constexpr context

Tags: c++, c++20, string-view, if-constexpr

Is it possible to compare std::string_view using "if constexpr" in a constexpr context? And why is_hello_2 and is_hello_4 fail to compile showing error: "‘s’ is not a constant expression"

```
static constexpr bool is_hello_1(auto s) {
  return s == "hello";
}

static constexpr bool is_hello_2(auto s) {
    if constexpr (s == "hello") {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

static constexpr auto is_hello_3 = [](auto s) {
    return s == "hello";
};

static constexpr auto is_hello_4 = [](auto s) {
    if constexpr (s == "hello") {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
};
```

Considering the main function (https://godbolt.org/z/zEcnb8):

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    static constexpr const std::string_view s1 ("hello");
    if constexpr (s1 == "hello"){}
    if constexpr (is_hello_1(s1)){}
    // if constexpr (is_hello_2(s1)){} // <- doesn't compile
    if constexpr (is_hello_3(s1)){}
    // if constexpr (is_hello_4(s1)){} // <- doesn't compile
    return 0;
}
```

Is there a way to fix "is_hello_2" and "is_hello_4"?

Comment: please focus on one question per question. The "why compiler(s) treats in so different ways" part is rather unclear. And please include the compiler error message in the question

Comment: @idclev463035818 Question updated

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/Kxec44

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there a way to fix "is_hello_2" and "is_hello_4"?

Remove the `constexpr` from `if`s in `is_hello_2` or `is_hello_4`.

> How to compare string_view using if-constexpt in a constexpr context

Normally, like anywhere else.

```
static constexpr bool is_hello_5() {
    constexpr const std::string_view s1 ("hello");
    if constexpr (s1 == "hello") {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Function arguments values are not constant expressions and you can't use them in a `if constexpr`.

Answer (score 3):

I won't use the formal standard wording, but rather explain the problem.

`if constexpr` requires that all of its arguments are always `constexpr`.

Arguments to `constexpr` functions are sometimes `constexpr`.

You can call `constexpr` functions with non-`constexpr` arguments.

Try `consteval`.

```
#include <string_view>

using namespace std::literals;

consteval bool is_hello_1(auto s) {
  return s == "hello";
}

consteval bool is_hello_2(auto s) {
    if (s == "hello") {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    static constexpr std::string_view s1 ("hello");
    static_assert(s1 == "hello");
    static_assert(is_hello_1(s1));
    static_assert(is_hello_2("hello"sv));
    return 0;
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c4427c0734efdb31)

You can put `consteval` in a lambda where you'd usually put mutable (I didn't recall this off-hand, so I didn't include lambdas in my sample code above).

Finally, I'd advise using anonymous namespaces to `static` functions local to C++ files, and use neither in headers.

---

This might not do everything you want; the advantage of `if constexpr` is you can do type-invalid things based on the branch.  And C++ doesn't let you do type-invalid things based on the value of a function argument; if it did, the compiler couldn't compile the body of a function without its argument values being supplied.

To get around that you can do something like create a compile-time string.

```
template<auto s>
consteval bool is_hello_2() {
  if constexpr (s == "hello") {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

and call it with

```
template<std::size_t N>
struct compile_time_string : std::array<char, N+1> {
    constexpr std::array<char, N+1>& buffer() { return *this; }
    constexpr std::array<char, N+1> const& buffer() const { return *this; }
    constexpr std::string_view view() const { return {this->data(), this->data()+this->size()}; }
    
private:
    template<std::size_t...Is>
    constexpr compile_time_string( char const* str, std::index_sequence<Is...> ):
        std::array<char, N+1>{{ str[Is]..., char(0) }}
    {}
public:
    explicit constexpr compile_time_string( char const* str ):
        compile_time_string( str, std::make_index_sequence<N>{} )
    {}
    explicit constexpr compile_time_string( std::array<char, N+1> buff ) :
        std::array<char, N+1>(buff)
    {}

    constexpr compile_time_string( compile_time_string const& ) = default;
    compile_time_string() = delete;
    
        
    constexpr auto operator<=>( compile_time_string const& o ) const = default;
    constexpr bool operator==( compile_time_string const& o ) const = default;
    
    template<std::size_t N_arg>
    friend constexpr auto operator==( char const(&lhs)[N_arg], compile_time_string const& rhs )
    {
        return std::string_view{ lhs, lhs+N_arg } == rhs.view();
    }
    template<std::size_t N_arg>
    friend constexpr auto operator==( compile_time_string const& lhs, char const(&rhs)[N_arg] )
    {
        return lhs.view() == std::string_view{ rhs, rhs+N_arg };
    }
};
template<std::size_t N>
compile_time_string( char const(&)[N] )->compile_time_string<N-1>;


template<auto s>
consteval bool is_hello_3() {
    if (s == "hello") {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}


static_assert(is_hello_3<compile_time_string("hello")>());
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ace29380ca93755d).

I pared down the compile time string a bunch.  You'll want better <=> and == and the like for more types.

Also, I think in C++20 you can make "stronger" compile time strings where the string actually lives in an auto argument.  But I'm uncertain.

Answer (score 1):

Think from the function perspective (as if you are inside the function scope): how can it parse your code in compile time if function arguments are unknown? That is the same reason you mark `s1` as `constexpr` in the main function. If you don't - the code won't compile.

So what you have to do is to remove `constexpr` from `is_hello2` and `is_hello4`. This doesn't prevent the function from being used in constexpr.

```
#include <string_view>

static constexpr bool is_hello_1(auto s) {
  return s == "hello";
}

static constexpr bool is_hello_2(auto s) {
    if (s == "hello") {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

static constexpr auto is_hello_3 = [](auto s) {
    return s == "hello";
};

static constexpr auto is_hello_4 = [](auto s) {
    if (s == "hello") {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    static constexpr std::string_view s1 ("hello");
    static_assert(s1 == "hello");
    static_assert(is_hello_1(s1));
    static_assert(is_hello_2("hello"));
    static_assert(is_hello_3(s1));
    static_assert(is_hello_4(s1));
    return 0;
}
```

But it is perfectly fine to use if constexpr on type and none-type template parameters:

```
template<int s>
static constexpr auto is_5 = []() {
    if constexpr (s == 5) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
};

static_assert(is_5<5>());
```

Unfortunately you can't have std::string_view as a non-type template parameter for now.